# function render_view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to load view using 1 global method in controller, 
this my method

```
private function render_view($view=NULL,$data){
      if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$view.'.php'))
    {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
    }
      $this->load->view('header/header',$this->data);
      $this->load->view('pages/'.$view, $this->data);
    }


public function index()
    {
      $this->data['title'] = 'Homepage';
      $this->render_view('home_content',$this->data);
    }

    public function shop()
    {

      $this->data['title']='Shoping';
      $this->render_view('shop',$this->data);
    }
```

this method called every link tag, like

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url ()?>Pages/shop">Shop page</a></li>
```

and generating view shop. 
but i have problem, every time i clicked the result is always the object not found. 
can you help me, oh i'm sory for my rip english xoxoxo

Answer (score 0):

change your methods to this and check

```
public function index() {
      $data['title'] = 'Homepage';
      $this->render_view('home_content',$data);
    }

public function shop() {

  $data['title']='Shoping';
  $this->render_view('shop',$data);
}
```

when you do `$this->data`, you are trying to access a property of the class which you don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your updated code

```
private function render_view($view=NULL,$data){
      if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$view.'.php'))
    {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
    }
      $this->load->view('header/header',$data);
      $this->load->view('pages/'.$view, $data);
    }


public function index()
    {
      $data['title'] = 'Homepage';
      $this->render_view('home_content',$data);
    }

    public function shop()
    {

      $data['title']='Shoping';
      $this->render_view('shop',$data);
    }
```